# Android Button Layout - Not Displaying Correctly

Tags: android, xml, layout, imagebutton

I am trying to get three images to display on the "welcome screen" of my Android app. Only one of the images is being displayed, and I cant figure out why... any Help?

XML File:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:gravity="center"
android:background="@drawable/main_bg"
> 
    <LinearLayout
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:paddingTop="30dip"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center"
    >

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/mnwvbutton"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginRight="15dip"
            android:background="@drawable/mnwvicon" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/reportsbutton"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/reportsicon" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/mnwvshowbutton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/showicon"
        android:paddingTop="30dip" />

</LinearLayout>
```

I have the exact same set up in another app, so I dont know why it isnt working here??

Comment: The layout works for me when I don't use images, so I can't figure out the problem without them or without knowing their actual dimensions.

Comment: assuming your first imageButton mnwvbutton takes all the space on the screen, then there is no place for other buttons. so you need to fix the sizes of the images i guess.

Comment: Sorry guys. I didnt have the app support the different screen sizes. I am not sure why this mattered, but once I added support, then it worked perfectly!. Thanks for your input though! Anyone know why this mattered though??

Comment: actually is there any way you can show us which result you get in graphical layout so we can help you.

Answer (score 0):

I think its because the last image is outside the inner linearlayout so put it inside the inner linearlayout and you should be able to see all three images in a row.

Answer (score 0):

Try scaling the images using the attribute android:ScaleType="centre" inside the ImageButton
or try a different layout like Tablayout for arranging the images in rows and columns with proper spacing.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry guys. I didnt have the app support the different screen sizes. I am not sure why this mattered, but once I added support, then it worked perfectly!. Thanks for your input though! Anyone know why this mattered though?? I dont know why supporting screen sizes matters?